# reversing "Windows To Go" - what am i doing wrong?

Tags: multi-boot, windows-11, windows-to-go, steam-deck

I have windows on external drive (was converted to windows to go from internal hdd using WintoUSB) - I use it with a Steamdeck and it works fine (Using the Steamdeck boot manager to select the drive to boot from).

I later upgraded the internal 1tb ssd, cloned steamos from the old ssd to the new one and installed a fresh windows installation. After a bit of tweaking both OSs boot and work fine.

Now, my goal is to replace the fresh install of windows with the one from the external SSD (TDLR it's my kid's machine and he installed tons of bits of software from all over the place which he doesnt want to lose)

SO, I have tried to clone the partitions from the external drive into the space occupied by the fresh windows install using Macrium Reflect. I have first used wintousb to convert the windowsToGo to local windows on the HD.

Steamos boot manager gives me the option to boot from windows boot manager but all results in BSOD.

One curiosity. I have tried it a few times, each time converting the external HD from WIndowsToGo to Local Windows and back again after the installation failed and my son wanted to use windows in the meantime. On my last attempt I didn't convert back yet the external drive boots and work just as before so I am wondering if wintousb actually convert back like it suppose to do...